# How to delete a node completely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gun

*gun 0.8.9, Node.js-to-Node.js*

I need to delete a node completely, leave no traces, not just remove its properties.

How can I do it?

Tried to open a parent node and delete its child node but entered the endless loop and kept receiving the following messages:

```
dinos in park { velociraptor: { statistics: { force: 9, speed: 15 } },
  trex: { statistics: { force: 25, speed: 5 } } }
dinos in park { velociraptor: { statistics: { force: 9, speed: 15 } },
  trex: { statistics: { force: 25, speed: 5 } } }
...
```

Source code:

```
const Gun = require('gun');
require('gun/lib/open');

const gun = new Gun();
const park = gun.get('park');

const velociraptor = park.get('velociraptor').put({
  statistics: {
    force: 9,
    speed: 15
  }
});

const trex = park.get('trex').put({
  statistics: {
    force: 25,
    speed: 5
  }
});

park.open(function (dinos) {
  console.log('dinos in park', dinos);
  delete dinos.trex;

  park.put(dinos, function (ack) {
    if (ack.err) {
      console.log(ack.error);
    }

    park.open(function (dinos) {
      console.log('dinos after trex deleted', dinos);
    });
  });
});

setTimeout(function () {
  park.open(function (dinos) {
    console.log('dinos after trex deleted', dinos);
  });
}, 20000);
```